# How I can copy a assets folder into the Resources folder of a macos bundle app using cmake?

Tags: macos, cmake

I'm building a macos bundle app and I need to include my assets folder inside the Resources one.

Right now I managed to copy standalone files in this folder but I loose the structure of the folder:

```
set(ASSETS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/textures/awesomeface.png)
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${ASSETS})

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
  MACOSX_BUNDLE ON
  MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}
  MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${VERSION}
  RESOURCE "${ASSETS}"
)
```

I could use a GLOB_RECURSE to find all the files inside the assets folder and move them into the Resources but if I do that I will loose the folder structure.

What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION` source file property:

```makefile
set(textures assets/textures/awesomeface.png ...)
target_sources(target PRIVATE ${textures})
set_source_files_properties(
  ${textures}
  PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Resources/assets/textures
)
```

Something like the above ought to work (though I don't have a mac handy to test it on).

See the docs here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION.html

Comment: I just want to copy a folder that has many files, with this I will have to go trough every folder and subfolder manually

Comment: @ellipticaldoor - I'm just the messenger here. The source file property is how you do this in CMake. You can make this less awful with CMake's path manipulation functions and loops.

Comment: I see there is no way, in the end I just used a custom command to copy the folder

Answer (score 0):

Just simply copying the folder works with a custom command

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets"
    "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/../Resources/assets"
)
```